# How to share private S3 object using an url?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using ruby v2 for this purpose. So, I want to make my object private and then share a link that can be opened up in the web browser. I used pre-signed URLs for this purpose. But, the connection's getting refused for some reason.

```
bucket = resource.bucket(name_of_bucket)
object = bucket.object(jey)
object.upload_file(file)
client.put_object_acl(bucket: bucket_name, key: key, acl: 'private')
url = object.presigned_url(:get, bucket: bucket_name, key: key, expires_in: 86400)
```

The client is an object of Aws::S3::Client which is initialised by the correct region, credentials and endpoint. (It's accurate as I'm able to create a bucket). What can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "the connection's getting refused"?

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED (IP address) @jellycsc

Comment: Just to narrow down the issue, if you add it not as a private object, 'presigned_url' work for you?

Comment: For public_object, public_urls worked.